# How to run a Python function from a Qt C++ project?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I've followed some tutorials and advice, I've even ran one function without problems, using `PyRun_SimpleString`.
I have a file called `tomograph.py` with a `makeFiles(path,alpha,n,l)` function I want to execute, and a `my_fun(x)` function that I managed to run (as I already mentioned).

This is what I do in my Qt C++ project

```
Py_Initialize();

PyObject* moduleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"tomograph");
PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(moduleString);

PyObject* function = PyObject_GetAttrString(module,(char*)"makeFiles");
PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(4,filename,alpha,n,l);

//PyRun_SimpleString("my_fun(5)");

PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(function,args);

Py_Finalize();
```

When I run this code I get a segmentation fault at

```
PyObject* function = PyObject_GetAttrString(module,(char*)"makeFiles");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't check whether `module` is valid before using it in `PyObject_GetAttrString(module,(char*)"makeFiles")`. If a previous call failed it's probably a `nullptr`. Watch this in the debugger to become sure. In general, you should add checking to your C++ code, concerning this.

Comment: Okay, so I added some checks and turns out there really is a problem with importing the module. Where should I put the .py file to ensure my app finds it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PYTHONPATH` to the working directory and putting the `.py` file in the build folder should do the trick:

```
setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
Py_Initialize();
```

Comment: This was moved from the question posted as a "Fix" edit. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que